# Php, files get bigger with full path name?

Tags: php, download

Working with a small download script along the lines of:

```
$file = "$tempDir/download.zip";
if($file) {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    readfile($file);
}
```

When this php script is placed next to the download source, and uses just "download.zip", it works fine
But otherwise I get some kind of junk-file of the same name, which is 10 kb instead of the expected 1 kb

Comment: Your downloaded 'junk' file may contain a PHP error that would be useful to discovering the solution. If you try to open it with a text editor it may help you find out what's wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code $file is always == true

It would be better to replace

```
if($file)
```

with

```
if(file_exists($file) && is_readable($file))
```

to be sure that the file is OK.